# Simulating Multi Touch UIAutomation in Instruments on iOS device

Tags: multi-touch, ios-ui-automation

Can someone point me in the right direction for how to simulate a multi touch tap in Instruments?

There are a few functions in which the number of touches is a parameter, but I don't understand how to actually define the coordinates of each touch.

For example, I need to simulate the user holding down a touch (or tap) at coordinate x1,y1 and x2, y2.

The application is not using standard accessible UI objects so I can only use coordinates.

Comment: I don't think there is a supported way to do targeted touches like that, but I've read that if you use the rotateWithOptions in a view that isn't scrollable it will be interpreted as a tap so you might be able to hack something together like that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following should represent a held tap at specific coordinates, but it's only a single finger tap.

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].touchAndHold(1.7);
```

If you really need a two finger
Try performing a swipe action that doesn't move very far

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()[1].cells()[2].dragInsideWithOptions({startOffset:{x:0.0, y:0.1}, endOffset:{x:0.5, y:0.1}, duration:0.25});
```